# How to setup Tensorflow Serving as in TF website?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn and setup TF serving as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/)

I trained my model using retrain.py file and all necessary model files are in "saved_models" folder
[image]

Now, I want to update the server command

```
    # Start TensorFlow Serving container and open the REST API port
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
   -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" \
   -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two \
   tensorflow/serving &
```

I have a hard time understanding to change the example path to my current setup.
I don't understand how "/models/half_plus_two" got there since it's not available in the example folders.

This is what I did here

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "c:/tmp/saved_models:/models/1" -e MODEL_NAME=c:\tmp\saved_models\1\saved_model.pb
```

But it fails

```
C:\tmp\serving>docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "c:/tmp/saved_models:/models/1" -e MODEL_NAME=c:\tmp\saved_models\1\saved_model.pb
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you docker pull the tensorflow/serving image? Also, you need to provide docker run an "image"(the one that you pulled before).

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving
```

Comment: I did pull docker serving image. But what is run an image ? Is it in the example ?

Comment: So I see that I am running the image. The issue is that setting up the model path. Can you show me how I could change the path to the model and model folder with my folder structure ?

Comment: So basically what you trying to do is to mount(-v tag) a volume from your host machine to the docker image. The -e tag is the environment variable which would be the model that is mounted to your docker image.

docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
   -v "c:/tmp/saved_models:/models/saved_models" \
   -e MODEL_NAME=saved_models \
   tensorflow/serving &

Comment: Thank you, also there should not be spaces after commas.